# Change section BG on ahref CLICK

Tags: jquery, html, css

I would love to see how I get the following done:

When clicking on: A with class "people", "water", "wind" or "shower"
action: change background of "home" to specific color corresponding with those classes

So: if I click on a yellow "people", I want the whole page to have yellow too.

I have tried it with this code, and got it working, but I want the code to be less specific and more usable in general! I know this can be done but Im lost as to how its done haha...

example :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".parent").click(function() { //add event to class
    $("#home").css("background-color", "black"); //change property
  });
});
```

```css
.shower {
  background-color: #652D90;
}
.people {
  background-color: #29B473;
}
.water {
  background-color: #2B388F;
}
.city {
  background-color: #FAAF40;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="home">
  <section>
    <a href="#">
      <div class="parent city">
        <div class="child-hidden">City</div>
      </div>
    </a>
    <div class="parent water">
      <div class="child-hidden">Water</div>
    </div>
    <div class="parent people">
      <div class="child-hidden">People</div>
    </div>
    <div class="parent shower">
      <div class="child-hidden">Shower</div>
    </div>
  </section>
```

I tried doing it in the way that it first deselects a class, and then adds another but I cant get it to work for these 4 different colors/classes :/ I know you can use "this" to fix this issue but I don't exactly know.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/5u2xnxtz/3/

Comment: You forgot to include jQuery in your fiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably going to be a lot easier if you use custom data attributes:

```
<section>
    <div class="parent city" data-color="#FAAF40">
        <div class="child-hidden">City</div>
    </div>
    <div class="parent water" data-color="#2B388F">
        <div class="child-hidden">Water</div>
    </div>      
    <div class="parent people" data-color="#29B473">
        <div class="child-hidden">People</div>
    </div>
    <div class="parent shower" data-color="#652D90">
        <div class="child-hidden">Shower</div>
    </div>  
</section>
```

Then pull this attribute on click and assign:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".parent").click(function(){ //add event to class
        var color = $(this).data("color")
        $("#home").css("background-color", color); //change property
    });
});
```

Comment: This is awesome! Thanks a lot :) new to that data-color, great feat.

Comment: @GandoeDyck -- It's not just limited to `data-color` - it can be `data-*` anything - prefixing with `data-` ensures that the HTML markup will pass validation.

Comment: Another question : Is it possible, when pressing on one of those divs, to make/let it stay 5vh? now when i hover, "this" enlarges from 3vh to 5vh(:hover). When i mouse-out it goes back to 3vh.

I would like for the div to stay 5vh and start playing a sound(.mp3/.wav). the idea of this is to have 4 different sounds and the user can choose which "mood" he/she is in and adjust the sound from my website along with his or her's mood if you catch my drift :)

Comment: another question, is it possible to add a duration to the .css? when i press on a div and the color goes form white to green, i dont want it to jump but fade in

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be getting their background color using `$(this).css('backgroundColor');`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".parent").click(function(){ //add event to class
        var color = $(this).css('backgroundColor');
        $("#home").css("background-color", color); //change property
    });
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5u2xnxtz/6/)

Answer (score 0):

```js
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".parent").click(function(){ //add event to class
            if($(this).hasClass('selected')){
                $(this).removeClass('selected');
            }
            else{
                $(".parent").removeClass('selected');
                $(this).addClass('selected');
            }
            $("#home").removeClass().addClass($(this).attr('class')).removeClass('parent').removeClass('selected');
        });
    });
```

```css
    #home{
        padding:20px;
    }
    .shower{
    background-color: #652D90;
    
    }
    .people{
    background-color: #29B473;
    
    }
    .water{
    background-color: #2B388F;
    
    }
    .city{
    background-color: #FAAF40;
    
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="home">
    <section>
    <div class="parent city">
        <div class="child-hidden">City</div>
    </div>
    <div class="parent water">
        <div class="child-hidden">Water</div>
    </div>      
    <div class="parent people">
        <div class="child-hidden">People</div>
    </div>
    <div class="parent shower">
        <div class="child-hidden">Shower</div>
    </div>  
    </section>
```